# What is the fastest way to compute the sum of the singular values of a matrix?

Tags: svd

Is there a faster way to compute the nuclear norm (trace norm, sum of singular values) of a matrix A than computing SVD(A) directly (or diagonalizing A^*A)?

I am particularly interested in the case where A is square. Assuming that A is real would be OK too. I am thinking in the limit of large matrices.

Comment: This was posted to Mathematics SE [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43688/fast-computation-estimation-of-the-nuclear-norm-of-a-matrix)

Comment: Are you really just interested in computing this norm, or are you interested in finding a matrix that minimizes the norm perhaps subject to some constraints?  Do you have reason to believe that your matrix is of low rank?

Comment: For my problem I already know the minimum, or I'm not interested in it anyway. I expect it to be nearly full-rank. Thanks

Comment: The intuition here is that computing this one number from a matrix should be easier than iteratively computing the whole singular value spectrum to great accuracy. However, I haven't come up with anything.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your scenario, perhaps you could make use of the result from this paper by Recht, Fazel and Parrilo, *["Guaranteed Minimum-Rank Solutions of Linear Matrix Equations
via Nuclear Norm Minimization"](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~brecht/papers/07.rfp.lowrank.pdf)*, **2007**.

If the matrix $X$ has rank upper-bounded by $r$, then:

$$
\left \Vert X \right\Vert_* = \mathrm{inf}_{L,R} \left[\frac{1}{2}\left \Vert L \right\Vert_F^2 + \frac{1}{2}\left \Vert R \right\Vert_F^2 : X = LR^{T}\right ]
$$

[Feng, Xu and Yan](http://guppy.mpe.nus.edu.sg/~mpexuh/papers/Stochastic_online_pca.pdf) used this result to derive their online robust PCA algorithm to remove any need for a singular value decomposition.

Comment: you just repeated the answer given in MathExchange.